# CSS - Need to make two shapes with different animations. Cannot alter the HTML

Tags: html, css, animation

This is one of the challenges for my course and I am struggling with creating two rectangles with two div's with same classes. I can create one rectangle to do one of the animations but have no clue how to create the other rectangle. Here are the instructions.

Using CSS, style the two divs with the 'bar' class. Each bar should be a rectangle that is 200px wide and 60px high. Each bar must have a background color of #444444.
The bars should appear horizontally stacked on one another so that they resemble an equals (=) sign. The spacing between the bars should be 60px. The equals sign should be horizontally centered within the screen.

Animate the equals sign so that the top bar moves to the left of the screen 200px and the bottom bar moves to the right of the screen 200px. Then, the bars should move to the opposite sides of the screen. Animate the bars such that they oscillate to opposite sides of the screen. Each oscillation should have a duration of 3 seconds. The animation should play on a loop.

```css
.bar {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #444444;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: bar; 
  animation-timing-function:linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes bar {
  
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(200px);
            transform: translateX(200px);
         
  }

  25% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(000px);
            transform: translateX(000px);
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(200px);
            transform: translateX(200px);
  }

  75% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(400px);
            transform: translateX(400px);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(200px);
            transform: translateX(200px);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS Challenges</h1>
<section>
  <h2>Challenge 2</h3>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: You can select the second bar as the :nth-child(2) to give it a different animation.

Answer (score 2):

Distribute the rectangles with *flex* and then apply `animation-direction` to the different blocks with `normal` and `reverse` respectively:

```css
body { text-align: center; }
section { display: flex; flex-flow: column nowrap; }

.bar {
  height: 60px; width: 200px;
  background-color: #444444;
  margin: 30px auto;
  animation: bar 3s linear infinite;
}
.bar:first-child { animation-direction: normal; }
.bar:last-child { animation-direction: reverse; }

@keyframes bar {
  0%, 50%, 100% { transform: translateX(0px); }
  25% { transform: translateX(-200px); }
  75% { transform: translateX(200px); }
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS Challenges</h1>

<section>
  <h2>Challenge 2</h2>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</section>
```